# Requests payload is not working

Tags: python, python-requests

When I try:

```
import requests

data = requests.get("https://api.nomi.com/api/admin/stores?v=3&k=XXXXXXX&account=XXX+XXX", verify=False)  

print data.text
```

I get the appropriate response.

But when I try:

```
import requests

payload  = {"v": "3", "k": "XXXXXXX", "account": "XXX XXX"}

data = requests.get("https://api.nomi.com/api/admin/stores?", data=payload, verify=False)  

print data.text
```

I get a 401 unauthorized response.

Any idea why?

Comment: compare urls with print(data.url)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `params` option, not `data`:

```
data = requests.get("https://api.nomi.com/api/admin/stores", params=payload, verify=False)
```

`params` is for the URL parameters, `data` is for the body (which is ignored for `GET` requests).